# Trouble creating a custom annotation class in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm trying to make a custom MKAnnotation class so it can hold additional information but i keep getting this error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [AnnotationForId setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16f63340'
```

I've tried looking up how to create one and i've followed what i've found online and i'm confused at why i keep getting this error.

Here is my custom annotation class.

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AnnotationForId : NSObject <MKAnnotation >{
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSInteger shopId;
}
@property(nonatomic)NSInteger shopId;
@property (nonatomic,  copy) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
@end
```

I've synthesized the property variables in .m class.

I try to call the custom class in my main controller:

```
for(Shop *shops in feed.shops){
        NSLog(@"reached");
        AnnotationForId *shop = [[AnnotationForId alloc] init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(shops.latitude, shops.longitude);
        shop.coordinate = coords;
        //[[CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(shops.latitude, shops.longtitude)]];
        shop.title = shops.name;
        shop.subtitle = @"Coffee Shop";
        [map addAnnotation:shop];
    }
```

Any help to why this isnt working would be awesome. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're trying to set your readonly property.

You declared it as readonly:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
```

But then you're trying to use setter:

```
shop.coordinate = coords;
```

**readonly** means that no setter will be defined for other classes to leverage.

**Edit:**
I think you should add convenience initializer to your `AnnotationForId` class like:

```
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord
{ 
    self = [super init]; // assuming init is the designated initialiser of the super class
    if (self)
    { 
        coordinate = coord;
    }
    return self;  
}
```

So your code will look like this:

```
for(Shop *shops in feed.shops){
        NSLog(@"reached");
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(shops.latitude, shops.longitude);
        AnnotationForId *shop = [[AnnotationForId alloc] initWithCoordinate:coords];
        //[[CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(shops.latitude, shops.longtitude)]];
        shop.title = shops.name;
        shop.subtitle = @"Coffee Shop";
        [map addAnnotation:shop];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is Simple Example For how to Create Custom AnnotationView.**

Create custom `AnnotationView`:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface AnnotationView : MKPlacemark

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subtitle;

// you can put here any controllers that you want. (such like UIImage, UIView,...etc)

@end
```

And in `.m file`

```
#import "AnnotationView.h"

@implementation AnnotationView

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate addressDictionary:(NSDictionary *)addressDictionary
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:addressDictionary]))
    {
        self.coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

// Use Annotation Add `#import "AnnotationView.h"` in your relevant `.m file`:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pCoordinate ;
pCoordinate.latitude = LatValue;
pCoordinate.longitude = LanValue;

// Create Obj Of  AnnotationView class  

AnnotationView *annotation = [[AnnotationView alloc] initWithCoordinate:pCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] ;

    annotation.title = @"I m Here";
    annotation.subtitle = @"This is Sub Tiitle";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

**Above is simple Example of how to create `AnnotationView`.**

Comment: You do not need to post the same answer on every same topic related, once is enough...

Answer (score 0):

You have given the property as readonly, which sets only a getter method for the property. So please make the property retain and try it once again.